# How to retrieve images in BLOB format from MySQL database and display in an html <img> tag?

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, blob

I created a MySQL database with a table using phpmyadmin. I created this table with a BLOB column to hold a .jpg file.

At the moment i'm trying to display the image (BLOB) in an HTML  tag to no success. I'm only getting the broken image icon when running the code.

Note: I know it's not recommended to do this, but currently i have too.

I've already tried looking up various questions here in stackoverflow.com, quora.com, and codeofaninja.com, and tried implementing various solutions that seemed to have worked for other people, but they haven't worked for me.

Where i'm displaying the information (test.php):

```
<html>
     <img src="getImage.php?id=10" width="175" height="200" />
</html>
```

Code i'm trying to use to display image (getImage.php)

```
<?php
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysqli_select_db("unirentas");
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      // do some validation here to ensure id is safe

      $sql = "SELECT imagen FROM propiedades WHERE ID_renta=$id";
      $result = mysqli_query("$sql");
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
      mysqli_close($link);

      header("Content-type: image/jpg");
      echo $row['imagen'];
?>
```

This should be displaying all the rows that are within the database along with the same image, but what it does is display all the rows with their corresponding information and the broken image.

Comment: If you open `getImage.php` in a new browser window, you should see errors. That's because your calls to `mysqli_select_db()` and `mysqli_query()` are missing the `$link` argument. Why aren't you using the object-oriented api (i.e. `$link->select_db()` and `$link->query()`) like you are in `test.php`?

Comment: `Note: I know it's not recommended to do this, but currently i have too.` Why? is there a specific reason you need this way? Perhaps this is an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) we can help you with?

Comment: Thank you for responding. The thing is i'm currently working on a school project , i'm pretty much a beginer in this and i'm using a java project to insert data into the MysQL database, the only way i found to do it was using the BLOB type.

Comment: And in regards to your first question,  both code blocks are derived  from other solutions i tried from stackoverflow questions. Like i said i'm really just at a beginner level  and i'm not sure how everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is that you have written a program which does lots of things and are then trying to work out why none of them are working. You should have created a Minimal, Verifiable and Complete script to test this and fix that first - the entirety of the first script you posted here should be replaced with:

```
<html>
<img src="getImage.php?id=10" />
</html>
```

You should also have posted the code which writes the data to the database.Neither you nor we know if the problem is with the data written to the database or is occurring when you retrieve the data.

You should also be checking that you're error logging/reporting is working correctly and that PHP is not already telling you what the error is.

Other things you can try are writing the data to a file and checking if it you really do have a image file, looking at the headers returned by getimage.php to make sure they are what you expect.

Finally, do take some time to learn a little about secure programming before you pug code like this into the internet - there are a lot of security problems here.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'll take what you said into consideration and edit my post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem, i used the base64_encode($blob); function

```
<?php
// Server credentials 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "unirentas";

// Creating mysql connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Checking mysql connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Writing a mysql query to retrieve data 
$sql = "SELECT ID_renta, calle, smz, mz, lote, precio, universidad, fecha, imagen, nombre, telefono, correo FROM propiedades";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // Show each data returned by mysql
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $ID_renta = $row["ID_renta"];
      $calle = $row["calle"];
      $smz = $row["smz"];
      $mz = $row["mz"];
      $lote = $row["lote"];
      $precio = $row["precio"];
      $universidad = $row["universidad"];
      $fecha = $row["fecha"];
      $blob = $row["imagen"];
      $nombre = $row["nombre"];
      $telefono = $row["telefono"];
      $correo = $row["correo"];


echo "

    <!-- USING HTML HERE : -->

    <p> ID : $ID_renta</p>
    <p> Calle : $calle </p>
    <p> Smz : $smz </p>
    <p> Mz : $mz </p>
    <p> Lote : $lote </p>
    <p> Precio :  $precio </p>
    <p> Universidad : $universidad </p>";
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($blob).'"/>';
    echo "<p> Fecha_  $fecha  </p>
    <p> Nombre :  $nombre  </p>
    <p> Telefono :  $telefono </p>
    <p> Correo :  $correo  </p>
    <p>////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////</p>

";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

// Closing mysql connection
$conn->close();
?>
```